# Trigger a cron job on custom form submit in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cron

Can I trigger a cron job at the time of form submission?

Actually, I need to download a product pdf when the form gets submitted.

But my pdf file has a large amount of data. So the site gets slow down.

So that I have moved on to cron.

I've successfully set a cron by referring this [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cron-job/).

Here is my code,

**/etc/crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">

<group id="default">
    <job name="test_cronjob" instance="Test\CatalogPrint\Cron\Pdfdownload" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

**Cron/Pdfdownload.php**

```
<?php

namespace Test\CatalogPrint\Cron;
class Pdfdownload extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    // doing my stuff on here
}
?>
```

And my form in the template file,

**form.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post" class="downloadPDF-account">
    <label>Brochure Name: <input name="pdfname" type="text" /></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Download" />
</form>
```

Actually now in this form action `<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>'`  , I given my controller path.

But I need to run my cron file (`Test\CatalogPrint\Cron\Pdfdownload`) on here.

If I'm doing the same stuff on my controller, means it takes too much time and slow down my site.

Please help me. I am a novice in magento and I am stuck at this point. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot trigger a cron on any particular event. But you can do something like this in your case.

> 1. Save the form in the database as submitted.
> 2. Run a cron job maybe every minute. Check if there is any form submitted and email is not sent. Here generate the PDF and send it to
>      the customer via email as an attachment.
> 3. Mark the record as email sent so that next time when cron is executed it will not resend the email.

Hope it finds helpful.